# Spring Boot 1.4.0.RELEASE and Spring 4.3.2.RELEASE

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to update my project to `Spring Boot 1.4.0.RELEASE` and `Spring 4.3.2.RELEASE` but it fails with a following errors:

```
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete:
Cannot find the class file for org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertySourceFactory.
Cannot find the class file for org.springframework.core.NestedRuntimeException.
```

Does `Spring Boot 1.4.0.RELEASE` support `Spring 4.3.2.RELEASE` and if so what am I doing wrong and how to fix it ?

Comment: Why are you including the spring framework dependency if spring boot dependency already includes it?

Comment: Goog question.. honestly I don't remember.. I think there are some cross references from other libs with a wrong(oldest) spring artifacts.. and I have to override this with a corect Spring version..

Answer (score 0):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38729974/service-dont-start-after-upgrading-to-spring-boot-1-4/38736226#38736226) for someone trying to do the same. You basically have to use dependency management to get your dependencies straight.